# '[AnyObject]!' is not convertible to 'SequenceType'

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, xcode6

I'm getting this error on the following code:

```
// '[AnyObject]!' is not convertible to 'SequenceType'
for connection in still_output!.connections {}
```

But it doesn't make any sense, because still_output!.connections is returning a [AnyObject]!, and I should be able to interate on an array.

I'm missing something really basic here or I have a bug on Xcode?

Comment: Also, still_output!.connections as [AnyObject]! gives me the error: [AnyObject]! is not convertible to [AnyObject]!

Comment: Xcode 6.4? And `still_output` is a `AVCaptureOutput?` optional? I might try purging derived data and restarting Xcode and see if that fixes it, because it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this works:

```
for connection in still_output!.connections as! [AVCaptureConnection] {}
```

But I still don't understand why it wasn't working before